# Micronaut Servlet support: discovery of classic HttpServlet implementations

Tags: servlets, micronaut

I followed the [micronaut-servlet guide](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-servlet/1.0.x/guide/) using Jetty Server and everything worked as expected (micronaut 2.0.0.M3, micronaut-servlet 1.0.0.M3).

However, for our Proof-of-Concept we need to migrate several classic HttpServlet (v3.1) based implementations to micronaut. Example:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Hello",
    urlPatterns = {"/hello/*"},
    initParams = {@WebInitParam(name = "name", value = "World")})
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().format("<h1>Hello %s!</h1><p>session=%s</p>", 
            getInitParameter("name"), request.getSession(true).getId()
        ).flush();
    }

}
```

However, this is not picked up by Micronaut. Is this not supported? If not, what is the best way to migrate this to idiomatic micronaut?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported by Micronaut. I found someone saying so in 2019 [here](https://gitter.im/micronautfw/questions?at=5cf78dca82c2dc79a55407f4) and I checked Micronaut's [documentation for the latest verision](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/) (3.x) and it seems to still not be supported. At least I didn't find any references for WebServlet or HttpServlet.